# Is there a way to add django models dynamically?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am creating models in Django using an array of strings.
E.g. let there be an array of strings named arr
`arr = ['one','two','three','four']`
Then I have to create four models in django named FooOne, FooTwo, FooThree, FooFour. All of them have the same fields. Is there any way where I wont have to create these models manually, i.e., I just update the array of strings and run a script and the models will be created for me automatically ? I am using MySQL as the database.

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea. Why do you need this?

Comment: Please *don't*. The idea is that models, fields of models, etc. should be static. Otherwise you make the application less predictable and more error-prone.

Comment: I was trying to implement database sharding in my django model. So the strings in the array are actually a column value in the original model. I wanted to do this in order to make separate tables in the db for each string entry.

Comment: (A) Do you really need sharding? Probably not is the answer. (B) There is more than one package that can help you with this ...

Comment: I need sharding because the model in order to optimise searching in the database. Search operation is getting quite heavy right now.

Comment: @SambhavJain can you share the model and the slowest/most frequent queries? Proper indexing will help a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 3 argument form of [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to create classes dynamically, if you use an abstract base class you can define all the fields there

```
class Base(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

arr = ['one','two','three','four']


for a in arr:
    locals()[f'Foo{a}'] = type(f'Foo{a}', (Base, ), {'__module__': Base.__module__})
```

As said in the comments though, this is generally a bad idea and probably will lead to some strange undefined behaviour